# PlayFramework: Check existing of record before creation

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to create a registration `Action` in play framework application. The question is how to implement check for already existing email?

```
object AccountController extends Controller {

  case class AccountInfo(email: String, password: String)

  val accountInfoForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "email" -> email,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText
    )(AccountInfo.apply)(AccountInfo.unapply)
  )

  def createAccount = Action {
    implicit request => {
      accountInfoForm.bindFromRequest fold (
      formWithErrors => {
        Logger.info("Validation errors")
        BadRequest(accountInfoForm.errorsAsJson)
      },
      accountInfo => {
        AccountService.findByEmail(accountInfo.email) map {
          case accountOpt: Option[Account] => accountOpt match {
            case Some(acc) => {
              Logger.info("Email is already in use")
              BadRequest(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> "Email is already in use")))
            }
            case None => {
              Logger.info("Created account")
              val account = Account.createAccount(accountInfo)
              val accountToSave = account copy (password=Account.encryptPassword(accountInfo.password))
              Created(Json.toJson(AccountService.add(accountToSave)))
            }
          }
          case _ => {
            Logger.info("DB connection error")
            InternalServerError(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> "DB connection error")))
          }
        }
        Ok("Ok")
      })
    }
  }

}
```

`AccountService.findByEmail` - returns `Future[Option[Account]]`

Unfortunately my solution always return 'Ok'

Comment: It's always returning `Ok` because you have `Ok` at the end of the `fold`. It causes the other results to be ignored.

Comment: @LimbSoup thanks =)I put it there, because otherwise IDE highlights my code as invalid. I need to return 'Result' in the accountInfo block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `findByEmail` returns a `Future`, you should use `Action.async` instead. This is because when you `map` the `Future[Option[Account]]`, you're mapping it to a `Future[Result]` instead of `Result`. Note how I had to use `Future.successful` with `formWithErrors` to keep the return type the same.

When returning a simple `Result` use `Action`. When returning a `Future[Result]`, use `Action.async`.

```
def createAccount = Action.async {
  implicit request => {
    accountInfoForm.bindFromRequest fold (
    formWithErrors => {
      Logger.info("Validation errors")
      Future.successful(BadRequest(accountInfoForm.errorsAsJson))
    },
    accountInfo => {
      AccountService.findByEmail(accountInfo.email) map {
        case accountOpt: Option[Account] => accountOpt match {
          case Some(acc) => {
            Logger.info("Email is already in use")
            BadRequest(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> "Email is already in use")))
          }
          case None => {
           Logger.info("Created account")
            val account = Account.createAccount(accountInfo)
           val accountToSave = account copy (password=Account.encryptPassword(accountInfo.password))
            Created(Json.toJson(AccountService.add(accountToSave)))
          }
        }
        case _ => {
          Logger.info("DB connection error")
          InternalServerError(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> "DB connection error")))
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Man, big thanks. It works great. Just to clarify: 1) We use `Future.successful` in the 'formWithErrors' block, because `async` is applied to `Action`? 2) We return pure Results in the 'accountInfo' block, because the are placed in the section which return `Future`? Thanks

Comment: You want to return `Future[Result]` within the `accountInfo` block, because `findByEmail` returns a `Future`. There is no way to get a plain `Result` out of it without blocking. So because we need to return `Future[Result]`, we use `Action.async`, which means *all* `Result`s must be `Future`s as well, thus the `Future.successful` to turn a plain `Result` into a `Future[Result]` to fit the required type.